# How to prove $((Q \wedge ¬P) \vee (Q \wedge P)) = Q$

Tags: propositional-calculus

I cannot see any steps to this problem! Surely the answer is obvious?
Is there a particular law which is used to make this statement?

$$((Q \wedge ¬P) \vee (Q \wedge P)) = Q$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be 
$$((Q \wedge ¬P) \vee (Q \wedge P)) = Q$$?

Comment: It's hard to say, because you haven't said what steps are allowed.  For example, if you already know that $\vee$ distributes over $\wedge$, the thing is very simple: you factor out the $Q$ from the disjuncts, obtaining $(Q\wedge(P\vee\lnot P))=Q$, etc.

Comment: MarkDominus yes you are right, I can see the answer now.
$$(Q \wedge (P \vee ¬P)) = Q$$ (Distributive Law)
$$(Q \wedge T) = Q$$ (Excluded Middle)
$$Q = Q$$ (Identity)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$(Q\land\lnot P)\lor(Q\land P)\equiv Q\land(\lnot P\lor P)$$ by distributivity. Or of course you can simply use a truth table, if you're allowed to do so in this problem.

Comment: @Mark: I'm sure that I didn't. Thanks for the quick catch.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of this makes me think of [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  You could start with $Q=Q \vee False$ But you could just do a truth table.